# coverity-sonar-plugin cannot connect synopsys repositry

Tags: sonarqube, coverity, sonar-plugin

I am trying to use "coverity-sonar-plugin" in the git hub below.
URL: https://github.com/coverity/coverity-sonar-plugin

Though I build my java project with the command "mvn sonar:sonar" after finishing all of the settings in README, I got "MojoExecutionException" in the "coverity-sonar-plugin" project.
So I tried to build "coverity-sonar-plugin" project itself in my local, I got 502 error for connecting the URL below, in the bottom of pom.xml
URL:http://artifactory.internal.synopsys.com:8081/artifactory/simple/sonar-plugin-local
Has others faced same situation and how to solve the problem?